# is it possible to prepend a string to output of cURL?

Tags: bash, curl

Looking at the man page for cURL:

```
-w, --write-out <format>

Make curl display information on stdout after a completed transfer.
```

Where it is possible to use this flag and append a string to the output of cURL. However I can only get this to append to the end of the output of cURL, because as the man page suggests, the -w flag appends *after* a completed transfer.

so doing:

```
curl -sS "http:/somewebsite" -w "hello_world"
```

will produce:

```
$
contentfromcurl
hello_world
```

....well how do you get the output to be

```
$
hello_worldcontentfromcurl
```

i.e. is it possible to get `-w` to *prepend* rather than append?

thanks to @Adrian, this is the final answer -

```
curl -sS "http:/somewebsite" | xargs echo "mystring"
```

cheers!

Comment: You could just run `echo -n hello_world ; curl -sS "http:/somewebsite" `

Comment: this also works fine for me. and preserves the result of curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
$ printf "bar\nquux\n"
bar
quux

$ printf "bar\nquux\n" | sed 's#^#foo#g'
foobar
fooquux
```

Obviously, you would replace `printf` with your `curl` invocation.

But this seems a bit like an XY-problem - what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: hi @Adrian - I want to be able to insert a string/variable directly before the content stored on the webpage (let's just say one line of text) - content which I am using curl to get. I have had luck doing this with the -w flag as in my question - however this puts the string directly *after* the content that curl gets. 

using your suggestion prints out the string before, however it doesn't print the content of curl, but rather echoes everything after the pipe instead of performing curl

Comment: one sec have misinterpreted your answer -let me try again.

Comment: yes this is correct. thank you @Adrian. I shall update my question to contain the final solution based on you answer

Answer (score 2):

If you're really desperate you can make a code block and include an echo.  The following will have the output you're looking for:

```
{ echo -n "hello_world"; curl -sS "http:/somewebsite"; }
```

As for getting the `-w` option to prepend, the answer is no:

> -w, --write-out 
>                 Make  curl  display  information on stdout **after a completed transfer**. The format is a string ...

Comment: *nitpick*: This is not a subshell, curly braces *avoid* the subshell as opposed to `( )`.